# Using Group By on Date Time field - Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to do a group depending on the DateTime field from the SQLServer Database using Linq query. Below is what I am trying

```
        var result = _context.sRProject
                             .Where(x => x.r_Project == rep)
                             .GroupBy(x => new { x.s_Date }).ToList();
        return result;
```

Here s_Date is the DateTime field within the DB.  I get the below error on the result like

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List, Model.sRProject>>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I have in the model class like

```
    public class sRProject : IsRProject
  {
    public DateTime? s_Date { get; set; }
    public string delivery { get; set; }
    public DateTime? delDate { get; set; }
    public string po { get; set; }
    public string so { get; set; }
    public string r_Project { get; set; }
  }
```

The SQL query I am trying to achieve is like below

```
   SELECT   [s_Date],[delivery],[delDate],[po],[so],[r_Project]
              FROM [sDev].[dbo].[PrjDetails] 
              where [r_Project] = @rep  
              group by [s_Date],[delivery],[delDate],[po],[so],[r_Project]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not really clear how `Model.sRProject` represents these values grouped by date. Indeed, the pre-grouped collection appears to be of type `Model.sRProject`, which makes things even less clear. By using `GroupBy` you are stating "I have more than one item with the same date, and I would like these returned in individual groups/sets for each date."

Comment: @John I dont nderstand the resaon for down vote/ closing the question. Since I am new, did try few things and reaching out for helping checking what could be the issue. I didnt know we have to change theModel, I will have to research on that

Comment: The reason for the downvote is that you haven't explained how you want your data formatted at the end of the method. We don't know what your expectation is, so it's difficult to answer. I've removed the downvote now that you've at least provided your model (it helps), but it's still not really clear what you want to do. I've provided a "best guess" answer and now I'm heading out for dinner so won't be able to reply for a while. I hope it helps.

Comment: @John The sql query I am trying to achieve is added to the question. I just initially added the s_Date in the  Linq query GroupBY and saw this error an dstopped adding the further more in to the groupBy clause. I am not sure what is Key in the answer

Comment: @John THe reason for grouping by is I will need to have a SUM(quantity field) that will be added in to the query. I Just wanted to do 1 step at a time. Am I stating the problem correct?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a solution since I don't use LINQ to SQL, and I know it doesn't always translate queries the same as you can write in C#. I believe your goal is clear enough now, so someone else should be able to help you.

Comment: whats the return type of this method?

Answer (score 0):

Frame a LINQ query like below:

```
var result = _context.sRProject
                             .Where(x => x.r_Project == rep)
                             .GroupBy(x => new { x.s_Date }).Select(x=>new sRProject{s_Date =x.Key.s_Date, delivery =x.Key.delivery, delDate=x.Key.delDate, po =x.Key.po, so =x.Key.so, r_Project=x.Key.r_Project }).ToList();
        return result;
```

Return type of your method should be **sRProject**